# Generating bottleneck feature augmentation with corresponding labels using Keras

Tags: python, keras, label

Using Keras, the CCN I wish to train requires I use image augmentation and transfer learning.

For the augmentation on a set of images on disk I use `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory`. To generate augmented bottleneck features on a pre-trained network I intend using the pre-trained network's `predict_generator` method with `flow_from_directory`. This already successfully generates the augmented tensor of bottleneck features. However, there appears to me to be no way to obtain the corresponding augmentation labels array.

I am really stumped as surely the designers of Keras thought of this and I'm just missing something obvious. I believe using the `_generator` methods in Keras have sufficient merrit to warrant persuing this route.

Thanks in advance.

```python
train_path = 'data/train'

train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=360,
    width_shift_range=0.10,
    height_shift_range=0.10,
    shear_range=0.52,
    zoom_range=0.10,
    channel_shift_range=0.10,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True,
    rescale=1./255,
)

train_flow = train_gen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=32,
)

train_number = 20000
train_tensor_neck = base_model.predict_generator(train_flow, verbose=1,
    steps=train_number // train_flow.batch_size + 1,)

# Now how to generate the labels? 
train_labels = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for xtrain, ytrain in train_flow:
    train_tensor_neck = base_model.predict(xtrain)
    train_labels = ytrain
```

Ideally, you should just stack your model onto the base model and not care about it (although the previous option saves training time):

```
base_model.trainable = False
for l in base_model.layers:
    l.trainable = False

stackedModel = Model(base_model.inputs,top_model(base_model.outputs))
stackedModel.compile(.....)

stackedModel.fit_generator(train_flow,...)
```